# AMD Processor Model Unknown

Tags: cpu

I just updated my processor on

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128394

GIGABYTE GA-MA785GM-US2H AM3/AM2+/AM2 AMD

from a

AMD Athlon II X2 240 Regor Dual-Core 2.8GHz Socket AM3 65W Processor

to

AMD Phenom II x6 1055T 2.8GHz 6MB Hex Core Scoket AM3 95W

1) I've cleared my cmos

but now when it loads I get the error AMD processor Model unknown, it will not load into BIOS, or windows, or any pre-windows tools.

Comment: You need to update your BIOS.

Comment: how can I update the BIOs without booting to windows or getting nto the BIOs

Comment: You install the old CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your BIOS to **F12f**

> Vendor, CPU Model, Frequency, L2 Cache, L3 Cache, Core Name, Process,
>   Stepping, Wattage, System Bus, Since Bios Version
>
> AMD, Phenom II X6 1055T, 2800MHz, 512KBx6, 6MB, Thuban, 45nm, E0,
>   125W, 4000, F12f

If its not working then its very likely you don't have the **F12f** revision of your BIOS.  Install your old CPU back in, update the BIOS, then the new CPU should work.

The above information is from the specification website for the motherboard.  I would normally provide a screenshot.  Due to the lack of complexity of the information and it being a single line I see no reason to do this.

Comment: do I need to the heatsink back on if I'm just gong to update the bios and take it right back off

Comment: @user417217 - Of course you do.  It will overheat within seconds if you don't.  If that happens in the source of a firmware upgrade you will brick your motherboard.

Comment: can I update bios from windows or is there different way

Comment: Follow the instructions provided by Gigabyte.

Comment: so this was fixed my BIOs not seeing the processor but when I load windows it still showing my old processor, I've cleared CMOS anything else

Comment: You installed the new CPU right?  You bought the new CPU from a reputable merchant?

Comment: yes, that is correct, and yes I did

Comment: I rebooted couple times and now everything is good.  thanks for all your help